# Binary incompatibility for Openssl on Raspbian

Tags: c++, openssl, raspbian

I have an application that is compiled and dynamically linked with Openssl 1.0.0. Its target was the Raspbian Jessie distro.

Running the application on Raspbian Stretch, results in error stating the libssl.so.1.0.0 cannot be found. The version of Openssl on Raspbian Stretch is 1.0.2, but according to Openssl website, these versions should be binary compatible (https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html).

I have tried to make symlinks from libssl.so.1.0.0 to libssl.so.1.0.2, but that does not work.

Running readelf against the libssl libraries:

```
readelf -d libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep SONAME
readelf -d libssl.so.1.0.2 | grep SONAME
```

Give these results respectively:

```
0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libssl.so.1.0.0]
0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libssl.so.1.0.2]
```

Should the library soname not be libssl.so.1.0 in both cases?

Has the Openssl libraries been compiled wrongly for the Raspbian distro?

Or what is going on?